# IOS swift3 tableview protocol implementation in different class other than UIController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement the Tableview protocol in a custom class of my own. My purpose is to develop a TableView library.

my sample class looks like this

```
open class TempTableAdapter : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    open var listTable : UITableView!

    init(listTable:UITableView) {
    super.init()
    self.listTable = listTable
    self.listTable.dataSource = self
    self.listTable.delegate = self
    }

    open func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1 ;
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "temp") as! TempCell
    let text = "hello"
    cell.label.text = text
    return cell
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print ("tapped")
    }

}
```

and my ui controller looks like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var listTable: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let adap : TempTableAdapter = TempTableAdapter (listTable: listTable)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what am I missing?
The problem is the `UITableView` is showing the default table, not using my custom class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter gets deallocated once the `viewDidLoad` methods exits, because it is a local variable. Instead, make it a property of the view controller:

```
let adapter: TempTableAdapter!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    adapter = TempTableAdapter (listTable: listTable)
}
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Such a silly mistake to make ! thanks for your help,it works perfectly now.